# how to set start index of nodes ID in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j

I know every time you create a node on NEO4j an ID is created for that node, however they start at 0, how can I set the id starting number, I would like to start at 1000 instead 0, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for you to dictate the starting value for a neo4j native ID. And you should also be aware that a deleted node's (or relationship's) native ID can be reused.

You should just add your own "id" property if you want to have control over the value range, and especially if you want to have a permanently unique value that will never be reused.

Comment: in the end when I create a new node I am using id:uuid() function of neo4j, plus I set that property to be unique, that solved my issue for now, thanks